# Cannot update sourcecode from remote repository to local repository

Tags: github, git-pull

I try to update source code from remote repository to local repository by git command:

```
$git pull origin dev
The terminal has noticed:
From https://github.com/AAA/BBB
 * branch            dev        -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

But the source code was not updated.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried confirming the `git remote -v` and see if it points to the right origin ?

Otherwise set the remote origin by 
`git remote set-url origin <remote-repo-url>`